# Looking for a demo website that uses the simplest form of re-use for multiple pages as possible

Tags: javascript, menu, web, include

In teaching students in an intro web class, I want to find the most straight-forward way of building a multipage static site of about 7 pages without having them have to make 7 different pages.

Obviously, I can have them make a separate header, footer, and menu file, and use server side includes, and just put the includes onto 7 different pages of content - but that feels dirty.

In the past I had them doing it this way: http://www.tropicalteachers.com/web110/?Ignore_WEB_119_CLEAN:MX_-old_Extra_Credit:Dynamic_PHP  - this was a quick experiment using the assignment as a model: http://www.yetirobotics.org/index2.php?pagename=team_yeti

but i feel like there should be a cleaner/simpler way to do it using javascript, or maybe in php - but i'm not sure of how.

Basically i'd like one main page with a menu -and when the menu items are clicked, it loads different content. I believe it's better to have the content in seven different files, but i could imagine it all being in the same JS within one page- remember, this site should be pretty simple.

I'd like to limit it to html/css/js/php, and preferably js OR php and not both.

with just the index page controlling (and loading) everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a more modern framework then you should look into using javascript for displaying content dynamically (as you suggested in your question). To do this I would make use of a framework like jQuery as it makes asynchronous request calling far more simple. To do this you would code a single page with a specific area marked for the dynamic content.

Server side you would setup either pages or a database to return the main content area that will change upon request.

Client side you can use jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to place the requested content into the content area.

```
$('#contentArea').load('url', function() {
     //callback area in case there is other stuff you want to do with js
     location.hash = 'blah';
});
```

It would probably make sense to change the page's hashmark so that pages still seem static and are linkable as content changes.

```
location.hash = 'blah';
```

In addition you will need to override default link behavior by returning false when they are clicked.

```
myLink.click = function() { 
     $('#contentArea').load('url', function() {
         //callback area in case there is other stuff you want to do with js
         location.hash = 'blah';
     });
     return false;
}
```

I think this would be a good lesson for students as it shows the differentiation between client-side, server-side, and how to connect them dynamically via javascript.